# Selecting a specific value from an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data that is an array of objects like this:

```
var cars = [ {"year": 2003, "make": "Toyota", "model": "Tercel"}
           , {"year": 2009, "make": "Toyota", "model": "Tercel"}
           , {"year": 1999, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
           , {"year": 2002, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
           , {"year": 2004, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
           , {"year": 2007, "make": "Honda", "model": "Accord"}
           ...
           ]
```

I want to pull out only the latest of each make and model, so that the selected array looks like:

```
var selectedCars = [ {"year": 2009, "make": "Toyota", "model": "Tercel"}
                   , {"year": 2004, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
                   , {"year": 2007, "make": "Honda", "model": "Accord"}
                   ]
```

I know that I can filter, e.g.:

```
var selectedCars = _.max(cars, function(d) { return d.year; })
```

but that returns a single object out of the entire array. I've also tried looping through a list of makes and models and selected just the max year, but I can't make that work.

Another option would be to nest the data via something like d3.nest() with make and model as keys, but then I'm not sure how to get back to my `selectedCars` goal.

Thanks!

Comment: `_` is underscore.js?

Comment: `groupBy` make. Select the `max`imum object per group (via `map`). `map` the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Underscore's groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function. You should be able to use that and chain it with `map`

```
_.map(
    _.groupBy(cars, function(car) {
        return car.make + car.model;
    }),
    function(years, makeModel) {
        return _.max(years, function(year) {
            return year.year;
        });
    }
)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydakd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
 var cars = [ {"year": 2003, "make": "Toyota", "model": "Tercel"}
       , {"year": 2009, "make": "Toyota", "model": "Tercel"}
       , {"year": 1999, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
       , {"year": 2002, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
       , {"year": 2004, "make": "Honda", "model": "Civic"}
       , {"year": 2007, "make": "Honda", "model": "Accord"}
       ]

var carGroup = _.groupBy(cars, 'make');
for (var property in carGroup) {
if (carGroup.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    var selectedCar = _.max(carGroup[property], function(d) { return d.year; }) 
}
alert(JSON.stringify(selectedCar));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/BEx5a/